# Pandas - How to pass column name in function

Tags: python, pandas

I might be missing something very simple here but I have a function that plots histograms for a certain column from a Pandas dataframe in certain time spans.  In my function I want to pass the column name as an argument.  This is what I have so far.

```
def make_hist(data,column_name):

    start=datetime(2013,11,1)
    end=datetime(2013,11,30)
    rng=pd.date_range(start,end)

    start2=datetime(2013,10,1)
    end2=datetime(2013,10,30)
    rng2=pd.date_range(start2,end2)

    start3=datetime(2013,9,1)
    end3=datetime(2013,9,30)
    rng3=pd.date_range(start3,end3)


    start4=datetime(2013,8,1)
    end4=datetime(2013,8,30)
    rng4=pd.date_range(start4,end4)

    start5=datetime(2013,7,1)
    end5=datetime(2013,7,30)
    rng5=pd.date_range(start5,end5)


    start6=datetime(2013,12,1)
    end6=datetime(2013,12,30)
    rng6=pd.date_range(start6,end6)

    plt.subplot(611)
    data.ix[rng6].column_name.hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()
    plt.title('December')
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.subplot(612)
    data.ix[rng].column_name.hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()
    plt.title('November')
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.subplot(613)
    data.ix[rng2].column_name.hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()
    plt.title('October')
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.subplot(614)
    data.ix[rng3].column_name.hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()
    plt.title('September')
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.subplot(615)
    data.ix[rng4].column_name.hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()
    plt.title('August')
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.subplot(616)
    data.ix[rng5].column_name.hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()
    plt.title('July')
    plt.ylim(0,300)
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.show()
```

The problem is that I do not know what data type the argument `column_name` should be.  It cannot be a string and it cannot just be a variable because I do not know how I would define it.  I feel like there is a simple way to do this that I am just not seeing.

EDIT: adding a description of the dataframe.  The output of `data.dtypes` is

```
account                             int64
first_active                       object
datelatest_inactive        datetime64[ns]
days_active                         int64
dtype: object
```

and my index is on the `datelatest_inactive` column

Comment: Could you give a small example of your dataframe (say two or three points from every month)?  It's always easier to test code when you can see what it's supposed to be acting on.

Comment: I can't really do that because the data contains very private information.  I could give you the output of data.dtypes if that would help

Comment: The actual data doesn't matter.  Something that we can copy and paste so we don't have to spend time mocking up our own example is considered customary (see [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: I think I found the answer. `data[column_name].ix[rng6].hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()` seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Even simpler is ``data.ix[rng6, column_name]``

Comment: This code should also be wrapped up into a loop-- the duplication is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
data[column_name][rng6]
```

`data.column_name` would translate to `data[ "column_name" ]`, which is not what you intend

Comment: The data frame is indexed by a datetime column. I tried changing the first histogram to `data[column_name][rng6].hist(bins=[0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300]).plot()` but it says 'Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects'